# Pasar variable JSON-Ajax a variable PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json, array

Necesito pasar una arreglo/variable JSON/Ajax a una variable PHP, de tal forma que yo pueda administrarla en mi file.
Actualmente tengo esto en index.php:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#enviar").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var nombre = $("#nombre").val(),
 apellido = $("#apellido").val(),
 edad = $("#edad").val(),

 //"nombre del parámetro POST":valor (el cual es el objeto guardado en las variables de arriba)
 datos = {"nombre":nombre, "apellido":apellido,"edad":edad};

 $.ajax({
  url: "procesa.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: datos
 }).done(function(respuesta){
  if (respuesta.estado === "ok") {
    $('#myName').text(respuesta.nombre);
             $('#myApellido').text(respuesta.apellido);
             $('#myEdad').text(respuesta.edad);
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

```html
<form id="form">
<input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" accept="text/plain"><br><br>
<input type="text" id="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" accept="text/plain"><br><br>
<input type="number" id="edad" placeholder="Edad" accept="text/plain">

<input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
<hr>
<p>Name: <span id="myName"></span></p>
<p>Apellido: <span id="myApellido"></span></p>
<p>Edad: <span id="myEdad"></span></p>
```

Y en el archivo procesa.php, ak final tengo:

```html
header('Content-Type: application/json');
//Guardamos los datos en un array
$datos = array(
'estado' => 'ok',
'nombre' => $nombre, 
'apellido' => $apellido, 
'edad' => $edad
);
//Devolvemos el array pasado a JSON como objeto
echo json_encode($datos, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Pregunta del millón es, CÓMO OBTENER EN UNA VARIABLE PHP MI VARIABLE DE RESPUESTA JSON? Algo como esto:
**$mynewnombre = $_POST["qué variable capturar"];**
Se podrá? Porque actualmente lo coloco en un id de un span y funciona perfecto, pero no es lo que busco.
Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Es exactamente como lo escribiste, `$_POST['apellido']; $_POST['nombre']; $_POST['edad'];` o bien para chequearlo hace un `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: Gracias, pero ya lo había intentado antes, y de nuevo ahora. Probé de varias formas:
echo $_POST["nombre"];
echo $_POST["myName"];
echo $_POST["respuesta.nombre"]; y ninguna fuciona.

Comment: Y no te muestra algún error en el response o en la consola?